# Combining an image sequence with audio and make a video

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to take a video extract the frames and the audio.Then i do some compression on the frames and then i want to combine the image frames with the audio to create the video.

1.Create frames from video based on fps (lossless)

```
ffmpeg  -i  big_buck_bunny_480p_surround-fix.avi -q:v 1 ./vidtest/out%d.jpg
```

The problem here is that the quality of the image is `94` based on `graphicsmagick` , how can i extract the frames at original quality.

2.Getting the audio

```
ffmpeg -i big_buck_bunny_480p_surround-fix.avi  -vn -acodec copy  big_buck_bunny_480p_surround-fix.ac3
```

3.How do i combine the audio with the image sequences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you already understand how to extract the audio stream from a video, so we'll skip that step.

Let's assume you have a video file named `video.mp4` and an audio file named `audio.mp3`. You want to take stills from the video and create a slideshow with `audio.mp3` as the audio track.

First we'll extract the stills. `fps=1/10` means that frames will be extracted every tenth second. `-ss 00:00:5` means that we'll begin five seconds from the start. The first bit of a video is often a fade-in containing mostly black, so it might be desirable to skip that.

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:5 -i video.mp4 -vf fps=1/10 image%03d.png
```

Next we'll count how many images that resulted in. This will be handy to know when we're specifying the frame rate of the slideshow.

```
imgcount=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "image*" | wc -l)

echo $imgcount
```

The duration of the audio track would also be nice to know. With MP3 and similar formats, especially when encoded with a variable bit rate, estimation of duration can be fraught. To get around this the audio file can be converted into a WAV file, f.ex, and then the duration estimated.

```
adur=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=duration \
  -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 audio.mp3)

echo $adur
```

Now we'll recombine the images into a slideshow. `$imgcount/$adur` specifies the display rate of the stills so the duration matches that of the audio file reasonably well. `-r 25` specifies the actual frame-rate of the video. Not all formats and video players accept unusual frame-rates.

```
ffmpeg -framerate $imgcount/$adur -i image%03d.png -c:v libx264 -r 25 \
  -pix_fmt yuv422p slideshow.mp4
```

This will mux the audio file and the slideshow file and trim to the duration of the shortest of the two. This works if the container format supports the codec of the audio file, if not either the audio file has to be re-converted, or another container format chosen. I find Matroska (`.mkv`) very useful. In the case of `.avi` and `.ac3` or `.mp4` and `.mp3` there should be no problem.

```
ffmpeg -i slideshow.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -codec copy -shortest slideshow-sound.mp4
```

Comment: I already extracted the frames based on the original framerate of the video from the first command.If i choose to extract frame every 10 seconds i am going to lose data(frames)

Comment: @user2650277: Of course. Just adjust `fps` to taste, say 25?

Comment: Does `ffmpeg  -i  big_buck_bunny_480p_surround-fix.avi -q:v 1 ./vidtest/out%d.jpg` not does the same thing

Comment: It should, except it converts the frame to JPEG. PNG is a better choice if you want to minimize loss.

Comment: @user2650277 is this now solved? or you still need alternate solutions?